# Flash player not loading on Safari and Firefox in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, firefox, safari, swfobject

I have an rails 3.2 application that uses a Flash Video Player. I load the Flash player using [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject) (I also tried the [swf_fu](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://github.com/marcandre/swf_fu&ei=e84rUvqeK6XV0QX52YDgCA&usg=AFQjCNED5dB0ZWfD2orUOpacXLJqMxg2IA&sig2=kWaxslkotU_Aig3F4LqzfQ&bvm=bv.51773540,d.d2k) gem that works fine). I use dynamic publishing method because I have some flashvars.

It works fine in development environment, but the player doesn't load on Safari and Firefox in production environment, and just shows the background color. It's working fine on Chrome though. The swfobject code seems to be working, I have the same HTML on all browsers when I open the Inspector.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="VideoPlayer" data="/assets/VideoPlayer-e79c6b85d45b6d29d04fb4905e8c83dc.swf" width="480" height="390">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7">
    <param name="flashvars" value="[...]">
</object>
```

If I just switch back to development environment it works again. The only difference I see is the fingerprint in production mode. In dev, there is just `data="/assets/VideoPlayer.swf"` but the rest is the same.

Any ideas on this? Caching, asset compilation, compression?

Comment: Why the down vote..? Anyway it might be a problem with Heroku, as it is working on another server.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an asset compression problem. I turned off gzip compression and it worked again. Seems like Chrome Flash player handles this better..